# Sort list of results in nested field graphql - python - grapheneSQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, graphql, graphene-python

I have a question regarding the way I can sort a list of results in a many to one relationship using GraphQL.
Let's take the example from graphene-sqlalchemy.

The schema is:

```
class Department(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'department'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)


class Employee(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'employee'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    hired_on = Column(DateTime, default=func.now())
    department_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('department.id'))
    department = relationship(
        Department,
        backref=backref('employees',
                    uselist=True,
                    cascade='delete,all'))
```

And here is my Schema :

```
    import graphene
    from models import (Employee as EmployeeModel, Department as DepartmentModel)
    from graphene_sqlalchemy import (
        SQLAlchemyObjectType
    )
    
    class Employee(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
        class Meta:
            model = EmployeeModel


    class Department(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
        class Meta:
            model = DepartmentModek

    class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
        find_departments = graphene.List(of_type = Department)
        def resolve_find_departments(root, info) : 
            return db.session.query(DepartmentModel).all()
```

In my query I would like to access the list of employee from my department and order the results by name. My query could look like :

```
     query findDepartments(){
        findDepartments{
            department{
                employee(orderBy : 'name'){
                    name
                }
            }
    
        }
    }
```

But this query won't work. How can I achieve the sorting of the nested field employee ?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this, but a simple way is to create a custom resolver with the ordering that you want, i.e. something like

```
class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    find_departments = graphene.List(of_type = Department)
    find_departments_by_name = graphene.List(of_type = Department)
    
   def resolve_find_departments(root, info): 
        return db.session.query(DepartmentModel).all()

    def resolve_find_departments_by_name(root, info): 
        return db.session.query(DepartmentModel).order_by("name").all()  # this is a guess of how sqlalchemy sorting syntax
```

Comment: The problem here is that I want to order employees by name, not departments. Employee is a nested field inside DepartmentModel.

Comment: Gotcha.  This answer doesn't work for what you need.  The answer from @jorzel seems like it's on the right track (although it needs an indentation fix.)

Comment: @MarkChackerian thanks, i haven't noticed this issue when posting. I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You can override resolver for `employees`:

```py
    import graphene
    from models import (Employee as EmployeeModel, Department as DepartmentModel)
    from graphene_sqlalchemy import (
        SQLAlchemyObjectType
    )
    
    class Employee(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
        class Meta:
            model = EmployeeModel


    class Department(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
        class Meta:
            model = DepartmentModel
    
        employees = graphene.List(of_type=Employee, order_by=graphene.String())
        def resolve_employees(root, info, **kwargs):
            query = self.employees
            order_arg = kwargs.get('order_by')
            if order_org:
                # should check that `order_arg` is a column of `Employee`
                query = query.order_by(order_arg)
            return query.all()
       

    class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
        find_departments = graphene.List(of_type = Department)
        def resolve_find_departments(root, info) : 
            return db.session.query(DepartmentModel).all()
```